# Stop overriding for the development snapshot module

Tags: composer

I have a development snapshot for a module (*ABC-8.x-1.x-dev*). I added 4 Patches. Now the developer does commit updates to the module.

By running `composer update`, I will loose all my patches.

When I remove the module name from composer.json, the module gets deleted. I have read that I should remove the composer.json file within the module.

Is there some kind of sub-version that defines the commit or so, for example `"drupal/abc": "~1.0-dev-FD1512"` or `"drupal/abc": "~1.0-dev-221"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to tie yourself to a specific commit, you might consider using [composer patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) instead:

```
{
  ...
  "require": {
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.0",
    "drupal/abc": "~1.0-dev"
  },
  "extra": {
    "patches": {
      "drupal/abc": {
        "Fix for foo": "https://url/to/foo-patch",
        "Fix for bar": "https://url/to/bar-patch"
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Patches will be applied on install/update of the relevant packages.

Comment: An automatic patching mechanism? What is if the patch was already included in the last DEV? What is if a new patch must be created first?

There must be a way to stop composer from getting a library just by sticking to the already downloaded one?

Comment: @mogio, I suppose composer will give you an error stating that it failed to apply the patch, from there it is a look in the issue queue and see if it was rolled in. You can also follow issues on drupal.org and you will get a mail once something happens in the issue. You will be notified when a patch is applied. If you must use a specific commit, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314381/how-to-correctly-require-a-specific-commit-in-composer-so-that-it-would-be-avail

Comment: If you have multiple of your own patches going, then yes, you can specify a sha to lock into so the patches always apply until said issues are resolved. But you'll almost always want to get it rolled in and work with contrib.